# Ansible how to use expect to answer password reset prompts?

Tags: ansible

I'm running into an issue with using expect to respond to password change prompts in a playbook. I'm not sure if my actual issue is with expect, or sourcing env files

```
- name: Change user password post install
  shell:
    cmd: |
      source /my/path/to/env_vars env_name
      /my/app/bin/run.exe password
      
      expect "Enter new password:"
      send my_new_password

      expect "Re-enter new password:"
      send my_new_password
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/expect
```

The error I receive is related to the sourcing of the env_vars file, but I use this pattern elsewhere w/o issue. I'm not sure what is causing this outside of possibly setting the /usr/bin/expect arg.

The error I receive is:

```
wrong # args: should be \"source ?-encoding name?> fileName\"\n   while executing\n\"source /my/path/to/env_vars env_name\""
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It would probably help to see the file your are sourcing. Moreover, what happens when your run the above commands manually on your target server in the expect shell ? My feeling is that the problem resides in your sourced file.

Comment: I can source the file without issue. I do it in many other places in the same playbook. The file conditionally sets a few env vars.

Comment: Do you source it inside expect as well ?

Comment: hmm - I do not, I may be misunderstanding what expect is actually doing here.

Comment: You are also abusing the `shell:` task when you actually want [`expect:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/expect_module.html)

Comment: @mdaniel I'm using `shell:` on purpose, `expect:` doesn't always work if you cannot guarantee that `pexpect` is installed in the python env on the target host, so I instead pass the executable as an arg.

see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I have had a lot of comments telling me to use the `expect` module, which I cannot use b/c I cannot always rely on `pexpect` being installed on target hosts, and I cannot install `pexpect` if it's missing.

I ended up saving the passwords to env vars and piping them into the password reset command.

For example:

```
echo "$OLDPASS\n$NEWPASS\n$NEWPASS" | /my/app/bin/run.exe password
```

Ugly solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

why not use the user module to set the password?

[Ansible User Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html)

Here is a sample of how you can use it to change the password.

```
  - name: "Set the User1 Password"
user:
  name: User1
  password: "$6$OiWEruLjZYhW7/cl$DL0SdqxS1wx9n8U/EG6woYEwmUOdOQFucv/"
```

To encrypt the root password, you can use python crypt:

```
python3 -c 'import crypt;print(crypt.crypt("Set_password_here", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'
```

Comment: The password to reset is in a 3rd party application, that has to be set from their CLI. Otherwise, this is what I would use.

Comment: How about something like this then: 

`- name: Change user1 password
  expect:
    command: passwd user1
    responses:
      (?i)Enter new password: "abc1234"
      (?i)Enter new password: "abc1234"`

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out the formating when adding comments. Here is the correct formatting:

```
- name: Change user1 password
  expect:
    command: passwd user1
    responses:
      (?i)Enter new password: "abc1234"
      (?i)Enter new password: "abc1234"
```